# How to change text in HTML element from p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I'm just trying out p5.js. I'd like to change some HTML text (not on the p5 canvas) from p5. Something like:

```javascript
score_display = createElement("text", "Score: 0");
...
score_display.nodeValue = "Score: " + score; // doesn't work
```

How do I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is an `.html()` property in p5.js to change innerHTML of an element.

Admittedly difficult to find in their reference documentation. Perhaps they are deprecating? https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/html

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to do `score_display.value("")` .Then you can change score_display to whatever value you want and change the space in the parentheces to what value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Go tho the index.html and type in this code:

```
<h1>Score : <p id = "scoreText">0</p></h1>
```

After you put that in you html, add this code to your sketch.js:

```
function changeText(text){
  document.getElementById("scoreText").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Call this function and add in the score to the parinthisis to change the text

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but I figured I'd tell you the way I would do it.

After you create the button, set its id:

```
score_display.id('scoreText');
```

Then use querySelector or getElementById to grab it like you normally would in vanilla JavaScript and set the text using textContent.

```
score_display_element = document.querySelector('#scoreText');
score_display_element.textContent = "Score: " + score;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let score = 0;
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  scorecard = createP("Your score is " + score);
  scorecard.style("background-color", "white");
}

function draw() {
  score++;
  scorecard.html("Your score is " +score)
}
```

[Working example](https://editor.p5js.org/r-leyshon/full/kffNSymG8)

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with [`.html()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/html), it can lead to [cross site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks. It only makes sense to use `html()` when you're actually setting an HTML string and are certain it's been sanitized.

Safer is to use `.elt` to retrieve the native HTML element, then make an assignment to its `.textContent` to change the text.

```js
function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  const h2 = createElement("h2", "type into the input");
  const inp = createElement("input");
  inp.input(() => {
    h2.elt.textContent = inp.value();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

It's too bad p5 doesn't have `.text()` getter/setter in its API (at the time of writing).